# Insert new container option for widget Magento2

Tags: xml, magento, magento2

I want to insert a new container option for widget in module_Contact.

[image]

I create a file with name `default.xml` in `app/code/vendor/Contact/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` with the following code

**CODE XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="modal-container">
            <container name="modal.form" label="Modal Form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In `app/code/vendor/Contact/etc/widget.xml` I added this code to the end of file

```
 <containers>
            <container name="content">
                <template name="grid" value="default" />
            </container>
            <container name="content.top">
                <template name="grid" value="default" />
            </container>
            <container name="content.bottom">
                <template name="grid" value="default" />
            </container>
            <container name="modal.form">
                <template name="grid" value="default" />
            </container>
</containers>
```

I executed the command `"php bin/magento ca:fl"` but the option does not appear in admin.

Can you help me solve this?

Thanks !

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130276/magento-2-create-widget-container-to-display-in-admin-end-while-selcting-widget